# How can I invoke a foreground process from a background PowerShell Job?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, background-process

I'm working on a PowerShell script that provides console output and restarts the system several times during the script's operation. As soon as it starts, it registers itself as a Scheduled Job so that it can pick up where it left off after restarts:

```
$JobArgs = @(
    $ScriptPath
    ($ArgumentList -join ' ')
)

$JobScript = {
    param(
        [string] $ScriptPath,
        [string] $Arguments
    )

    $PSArgs = @(
        '-NoExit'
        '-NoLogo'
        '-NoProfile'
        "-File $ScriptPath $Arguments"
    )

    Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList $PSArgs -Wait
}

$AtLogonTrigger = New-JobTrigger -AtLogOn -User $LoginUser

$JobProperties = @{
    'Name'               = $JobName
    'Trigger'            = $AtLogonTrigger
    'ScheduledJobOption' = New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated
    'ScriptBlock'        = $JobScript
    'ArgumentList'       = $JobArgs
}

$Job = Register-ScheduledJob @JobProperties -ErrorAction Stop
```

However, while this does do what I want, it does so in the background when I would prefer that the PowerShell window be visible. It doesn't seem to be an intrinsic of PowerShell either; simply starting `notepad.exe` via `Start-Process` provides a hidden notepad instance as well.

While I'm aware that I probably shouldn't be relying on console output, it's good enough for my purposes.

**Is there a way to invoke a foreground process from a background job?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is by design. PowerShells jobs and Windows scheduled tasks are running in the background (Session 0) and should/do not interact with the user's desktop.

PowerShell jobs are really just Windows scheduled tasks, you can find them at:

> \Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs

The only way to run a scheduled tasks to interact with the desktop session is to set: `Run only when user is logged on`

With `schtasks.exe` you would use the `/IT` switch

The `ScheduledJobOptions` in the PowerShell cmdlets don't seem to let you specify this.

So you could try to manually find the scheduled tasks corresponding to your PowerShell Job and change that property.

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by using Scheduled Tasks instead of jobs. I was unable to find, anywhere, an answer to the question, but launching an interactable PowerShell session via Register-ScheduledTask was easy enough.